# <md-dialog> - Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Utilizo este componente  para abrir modais. Utilizo o parâmetro flex para definir a largura.

Como definir a altura ?

```
<md-dialog aria-label="Detalhe do bem" flex="90" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui assim:

```
<md-dialog aria-label="Detalhe do bem" flex="90" style="height: 600px">
```